# How to scroll at top of the page in ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

currently i am working in ionic framework on javascript and angular-js i just put the search box and render list of customer but suppose in first attempt i can search with 'a' it shows all item which having alpha 'a' but the problem is when i scroll down to see the search result list and at the bottom if i want to search with 'd' this time it gives result but at the top of the page but my scroll is at the bottom of the page.
So to solve the above problem i want set scroll position at the top of the page when search query is empty and display all customer so  what should i do to solve this problem

thanks in adv..

Answer (score 36):

You can try :

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate/

Comment: Thank a lot, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 23):

For Ionic 2 and higher use the `scrollToTop()` method on the content class.

page.html

```
<ion-content>
  Add your content here!
</ion-content>
```

page.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage{
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  scrollToTop() {
    this.content.scrollToTop();
  }
}
```

See http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#scrollToTop

Comment: This is not working. I am getting this error- Runtime Error
Cannot read property 'scrollToTop' of null

Comment: @SunnyKumar try 

```
this.content && this.content.scrollToTop() 
```

Answer (score 15):

For Ionic 4 this has been renamed from `Content` to `IonContent`, along with a new package name:

- [Breaking: Component Imports Changes](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/angular/BREAKING.md#component-imports)

Making the snippet look like this:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonContent } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage{
  @ViewChild(IonContent) content: IonContent;

  scrollToTop() {
    this.content.scrollToTop(400);
  }
  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.scrollToTop();
  }
}
```

Thanks @Junaid (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48987846/156388) for the base of this answer.

I didn't edit that answer as it's still valid for Ionic 2-3.

Answer (score 12):

I normally do this on my home page.

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage{
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  scrollToTop() {
    this.content.scrollToTop(400);
  }
  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.scrollToTop();
  }
}
```

Or you can call scrollTop() whenever you want. 
Note: 400 is duration in milliseconds, it is optional and you can use this as well

> this.content.scrollToTop();

in this case scrollToTop() will set the default value of 300.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above will scroll all your views to top. If you want to have more control then you will have to use a delegate handler .

First whatever you want to scroll you will have to add the delegate handler name

```
<ion-content delegate-handle="dashboard">
   ......
</ion-content>
```

In your controller you will have to use this handler

```
$timeout(function(){$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('dashboard').scrollTop(false);});
```

I would recommend using a $timeout because if there is current digest cycle it will not work. Also change **false** to **true** if you want to animate the scroll. Lastly dont forget to inject **$ionicScrollDelegate** and **$timeout** in your controller

Answer (score 1):

**For Ionic 4.X Latest Stable Release Try this**

**Source [Link](http://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-how-to-scroll-to-top-bottom-using-ion-content-scroll-events/)**

[image]

In Page add Angular variable id on **ion-content** tag

```
<ion-content
  [scrollEvents]="true"
  (ionScrollStart)="logScrollStart()"
  (ionScroll)="logScrolling($event)"
  (ionScrollEnd)="logScrollEnd()"
>

     <ion-button (click)="ScrollToTop()">
        Scroll To Top
     </ion-button>

</ion-content>
```

In **component** add methods

```
      logScrollStart(){
        console.log("logScrollStart : When Scroll Starts");
      }

      logScrolling(){
        console.log("logScrolling : When Scrolling");
      }

      logScrollEnd(){
        console.log("logScrollEnd : When Scroll Ends");
      }

      ScrollToBottom(){
        this.content.scrollToBottom(1500);
      }

      ScrollToTop(){
        this.content.scrollToTop(1500);
      }

      ScrollToPoint(X,Y){
        this.content.scrollToPoint(X,Y,1500);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ionic 4, the approaches here helped a lot. However, a second param was needed on

```
@ViewChild(IonContent) content: IonContent;
```

So, I set the static false, as suggested [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/scroll-to-top-in-ionic/52785/10). But it only worked for me when I changed:

```
@ViewChild(IonContent, {static: false}) content: IonContent;
```

to

```
@ViewChild(IonContent, undefined) content: IonContent;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ionic 6+ you need to declare the element's ID to refer to, you could use `any` when declaring the type, but to be specific you can set `IonContent` as per previous versions. This is obviously for the Angular flavour of Ionic.

So after you add the ID, for example I have called my content "content":
[image: naming the element]

Now you can refer to this element in the TypeScript via `ViewChild` as per previous versions.

[image: declaring the element as a variable via viewchild]

Now you can utilise the methods outlined [in the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#methods). For example:

[image: scrolling to the top when the keyboard is hidden]

Answer (score 0):

**For Latest Ionic versions:**

```
**temp.html**

<ion-content #menuPageTop>
  ...
</ion-content>
```

in typescript file do these changes

```
import { IonContent } from '@ionic/angular';
export class ChooseMenuPageComponent {
@ViewChild('menuPageTop') private menuPageTop: IonContent;
...
yourEventHandler() {
  this.menuPageTop.scrollToTop();
 }
}
```