# Scroll up when keyboard is open Ionic

Tags: ionic5

I am trying to design a login screen with Ionic and my fields are in the center of my page. When I select an input, I want to scroll up the screen to keep my field and my login button in the center of the app screen.
[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmE4G.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar layout and I found the best way to automatically utilise Ionic's built in scroll assist is to just simply add some `<br />` tags beneath your login form to create "scrollable space".

Furthermore, if you [check out my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74003167/4582132) for another scrolling related Ionic question you can see some other useful info in order to scroll back up once the keyboard is hidden.